# Unable to define a parser in Haskell: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’

Tags: function, haskell, types

I am trying to define a parser in Haskell. I am a total beginner and somehow didn't manage to find any solution to my problem at all.

For the first steps I tried to follow the instructions on the slides of a powerpoint presentation. But I constantly get the error "Not in scope: type variable ‘a’":

```
type Parser b = a -> [(b,a)]
item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
 [] -> []
 (x:xs) -> [(x:xs)]
```

```
error: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’
   |
11 | type Parser b = a -> [(b,a)]
   |                          ^
```

I don't understand the error but moreover I don't understand the first line of the code as well:

```
type Parser b = a -> [(b,a)]
```

What is this supposed to do? On the slide it just tells me that in Haskell, Parsers can be defined as functions. But that doesn't look like a function definition to me. What is "type" doing here? If it s used to specify the type, why not use "::" like in second line above? And "Parser" seems to be a data type (because we can use it in the type definition of "item"). But that doesn't make sense either.

The line derives from:

```
type Parser = String -> (String, Tree)
```

The line I used in my code snippet above is supposed to be a generalization of that.

Your help would be much appreciated. And please bear in mind that I hardly know anything about Haskell, when you write an answer :D

Comment: Type `a` needs to be introduced into the local scope, that is, it must be either a type argument of `Parser`, or a known type such as Char or Bool. As things stand, it is neither. You might want to try: `type Parser a b = a -> [(b,a)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a significant difference between the type alias `type T = SomeType` and the type annotation `t :: SomeType`.

`type T = Int` simply states that `T` is just another name for the type `Int`. From now on, every time we use `T`, it will be replaced with `Int` by the compiler.

By contrast, `t :: Int` indicates that `t` is some value of type `Int`. The exact value is to be specified by an equation like `t = 42`.

These two concepts are very different. On one hand we have equations like `T = Int` and `t = 42`, and we can replace either side with the other side, replacing type with types and values with values. On the other hand, the annotation `t :: Int` states that a value has a given type, not that the value and the type are the same thing (which is nonsensical: `42` and `Int` have a completely different nature, a value and a type).

```
type Parser = String -> (String, Tree)
```

This correctly defines a type alias. We can make it parametric by adding a parameter:

```
type Parser a = String -> (String, a)
```

In doing so, we can not use variables in the right hand side that are not parameters, for the same reason we can not allow code like

```
f x = x + y   -- error: y is not in scope
```

Hence you need to use the above `Parser` type, or some variation like

```
type Parser a = String -> [(String, a)]
```

By contrast, writing

```
type Parser a = b -> [(b, a)]  -- error
```

would use an undeclared type `b`, and is an error. At best, we could have

```
type Parser a b = b -> [(b, a)]
```

which compiles. I wonder, though, is you really need to make the `String` type even more general than it is.

So, going back to the previous case, a possible way to make your code run is:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
 [] -> []
 (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]
```

Note how `[(x, xs)]` is indeed of type `[(Char, String)]`, as needed.

If you really want to generalize `String` as well, you need to write:

```
type Parser a b = b -> [(b, a)]

item :: Parser Char String
item = \inp -> case inp of
 [] -> []
 (x:xs) -> [(xs, x)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question though: When type Parser = String means that Parser is the same as a String, what does type Parser a b = b -> [(b,a)] mean? I don't quite understand the syntax and that we use an arrow on the right side of the equation confuses me most.

Comment: @Kali It's a function type. If we write `type T = Int->String` we can then write `f :: T ; f x = "hi"` instead of `f :: Int->String ; f x = "hi"`. In your case `f :: Parser Char String` becomes `f :: String -> [(String, Char)]`.